# Imagemagick hanging and not working

Tags: command-line, resize, convert, image-processing, imagemagick

I have a folder full of `name*.jpg` files.

I found that *Imagemagick convert* is the right 'tool' to resize my images.

The command I'm using is

```
convert name*.jpg -resize 2000x1500 name*.jpg
```

Problem is, that it uses all my RAM (8 GB) so my PC hangs and after a while it starts doing something but the output files are not resized.

Does anyone know what the issue could be?
Size of all files is about 200 MB.

Comment: also tried other output names. Same result :/

Comment: so about the size problem if I use , with the exclamation mark after the size it works:

convert name*.jpg -resize 2000x1500! name*.jpg

Comment: `convert` does not accept multiple files as input or output. Also, if you want to overwrite orginal files use `mogrify` instead of `convert`.

Comment: @OcK More than one package can install a `convert` command in `/usr/bin`. You may be able to get more answers and/or an explanation of what happened if you **[edit]** this question to include the output of `lsb_release -a`, `type -a convert`, `apt list --installed '*magick*'`, and `namei /usr/bin/convert`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of:

```
convert name*.jpg -resize 2000x1500 new_name*.jpg
```

The following worked for me: (loop on every jpg image in the given folder):

```
for file in *.jpg
do 
    convert "$file" -resize 2000x1500 "new-$file"
done
```